# Evolute of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

i need a small help , any idea please how can i solve the evolute of a curve with this equation :
y^2(a-x)=x^3 
i know how to calculate and i tried to transform this equation in parametric equation but it takes 3 sheets just to do the calcul of derivative of x and i don't think it is ok , also i tried directly to derive from this cartezian equation also it gives me so complicated calculus i don't think it is ok any help please i need it so urgent i apreciate any help

Comment: First, you should actually post some of your work so we can see how you're approaching the problem and perhaps make some suggestions. Yes, ordinarily it's easiest to work with the curve parametrically. No matter what you do, you're going to need to find the curvature of the curve. Where did you get this, by the way?

Comment: i use the substitution y=tx this for parametrization

Comment: they are 3 pages of calculus i do not know how can i post them to show you how i work

Comment: If you look at posts here on MSE, people use MathJax and type up their results so that they are relatively easy to read. That's one of the prices you pay for getting help on this site. OK ... if you use that substitution, you get a nice parametrization. So proceed. But, yes, whoever assigned you this exercise expected some messy calculations.

Comment: ok thank you so much